# How to check in the model/controller if form input contains HTML (spam)? Regex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, spam

My app is getting about 1000 spam entries a day. The content is not linked anywhere so the bots effort is completely useless.

But its messing with our metrics and generating tons of encoding errors (the bot is submitting chinese characters).

The fields are simple text boxes and input fields.

What I'd like to do is ban any user who enters html into the field and submits it.

I can handle the banning aspect (logout them out, put boolean in users table) easily.

But I'm not sure how to check if the params contain html and where the cleanest place to check for this is... (before filter? model validation?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can always **use a regexp to filter out html from input**, e.g. delete anything between < and > .

```
input_string.gsub(/<.*>/m, '')   # make sure to use multi-line mode for the RegExp
```

or check if this matches: (if you want to detect if there was HTML in the input)

```
input_string =~ /<.*>/m
```

You could **put this in the controller**, so it cleans up the input right after it was posted, or you could put this in the validation, so it will fail on save.. Probably better in the controller.

But this will only get you so far - e.g. those bots may still keep posting forms.. which uses up resources on your end..

That's why I'd also recommend you use **Google's re-captcha** , which is really easy to add to Rails.

With the Captcha, you'll make sure that only humans can post to your site.

http://www.google.com/recaptcha

You can look at some **example code for how to integrate ReCaptcha into a Rails project** here:

https://github.com/tilo/mail_form_example_with_recaptcha

Comment: captcha isnt an option, I can't afford the user experiance hit a captcha would add. the content isnt publically linked anywhere and rails already blocks HTML in forms. My question is mostly just accurate detection on form input.

Comment: then the regexp should help - you could even put this in JS

Answer (score 0):

If there's no reason for a < or `&lt;` just check for angle brackets. If there *is* a legitimate reason, it'll be a bit more irritating, but probably still limited to checking for angle brackets and any of whatever tags you're trying to avoid.